# Matlab Video of logical images

Tags: matlab, video, playback, frames

I have a video where I apply chroma key to each frame to extract color.

```
newImage = (checkR)&(checkG)&(checkB);% for each frame
```

In the end I put all frames in similar video container like: 1x39(frames) of type struct where each struct now contains cdata not in int, but in logical. I get an error when I try to play the new video. I can view individual frames by extracting them, but I need a video.

```
movie(b); % doesnt work
```

gives error:

```
??? Error using ==> movie
Movie cdata must be of type uint8 array
```

Do I have to convert it to int?

OR

apply some binary mask which I do not know how to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to `uint8` by

```
b=uint8(b);
```

then call `movie`